# Cache-control metadata of aws S3 not caching images in browser

Tags: amazon-s3, browser-cache, cache-control

I am able to fetch images from S3 bucket using Storage.get(..) of aws-amplify and display it in my homepage of React app using `<img src={..}/>`.

I have set cache-control to public,max-age=31536000 in my S3 bucket by selecting all images in bucket > clicking Actions > clicking change metadata > Specifying Cache control > Save . The images don't seem to be cached in my browser as the response headers of images are showing status code 200 (and not 304) on refresh and also on going back to the page displaying those images. The images are also taking the same time to load as before. Below is the response screenshot :
[image]

Screenshot of request headers:

[image]

I had uploaded the images to S3 bucket manually by clicking the upload files button in S3 console and I am not using cloudfront with s3.

Comment: What are the request headers sent from the browser? Is there any cache busting query string added on every request?

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

AWS Amplify's `Storage.get` uses query string params for authorisation, so each request changes the url which bypasses the browser cache.

To avoid this you can cache the presigned url, however the url can expire either based on:

1. The expiry set when calling `Storage.get`
2. Expiry of the current user's session ID token (which can expire **before** the above)

I created a helper for which set's S3 `Storage.get` and `Cache.setItem` to expire at the same time, based on user's current session idToken expiry.

```
 export const getFromS3Storage = async (key, identityId = null, level = 'protected') => {
  let cachedUrl
  try {
    cachedUrl = await Cache.getItem(key);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('get cache url error: ', err);
  }

  // return cached url if it exists
  if (cachedUrl) {
    return cachedUrl;
  }

  const currentSession = await Auth.currentSession();
  const sessionExpiry = currentSession.getIdToken().payload.exp; // unix timestamp in seconds
  const timeStampNowSeconds = parseInt(String(+new Date / 1000)); // get now unix timestamp in seconds

  const expireUnixSeconds = sessionExpiry - timeStampNowSeconds; // get seconds from now to expire

  const options = {
    expires: expireUnixSeconds, // expiry UNIX timestamp in seconds
    level
  };

  if (identityId) {
    options.identityId = identityId;
  }

  const url = await Storage.get(key, options);
  try {
    Cache.setItem(key, url, { expires: sessionExpiry * 1000 }); // unix timestamp in milliseconds
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('error set image cache: ', err);
  }

  return url;
}
```